# Update SQL with CASE and SUM functions

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, case

I know this seems like a similar question that has been answered before, and it may be. However, I have looked through the answers and they seem to all work along the table.x = sum (case when (x))) example. None of them seem to work with getting a sum inside the CASE function.

My script before attempting to create an update script is

```
SELECT 
 Item
 ,Loc
 ,MinDRPQty
 ,NetNeed
 ,CASE 
    WHEN (NetNeed/MinDRPQty) <= 1 THEN MinDRPQty --use existing multiplier if  sum is less than multiplier
    ELSE CEIL(NetNeed/MinDRPQty)*MinDRPQty --determine appropriate multiple, convert to int, and multiply 
 END as "ExpectedOrder"
 FROM
 (
   select 
   s.Item as Item, 
   s.Loc as Loc, 
   p.MinDRPQty as MinDRPQty,  
   SUM (s.OH + s.UDC_ActualIT + s.UDC_CommitIT - s.UDC_AllCustOrd - s.UDC_ADJ_AvgDailyDmd*  (p.DRPCovDur/1440) - s.UDC_SafetyStock) as NetNeed 
   from SKU s, SKUPlanningParam p 
   where s.Item = p.Item and s.Loc = p.Loc group by s.Item, s.Loc, p.MinDRPQty
 )
```

I am looking to update a field called UDC_NetNeed. So I need the NetNeed from this statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this has been answered before, and I have missed it, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update SKU s 
set UDC_NetNeed = (
    SELECT 
      CASE 
        WHEN (NetNeed/nullif(MinDRPQty, 0)) <= 1 THEN MinDRPQty --use existing multiplier if  sum is less than multiplier
        ELSE CEIL(NetNeed/nullif(MinDRPQty, 0))*MinDRPQty --determine appropriate multiple, convert to int, and multiply 
     END
     FROM
     (
       select 
       s.Item as Item, 
       s.Loc as Loc, 
       p.MinDRPQty as MinDRPQty,  
       SUM (s.OH + s.UDC_ActualIT + s.UDC_CommitIT - s.UDC_AllCustOrd - s.UDC_ADJ_AvgDailyDmd*  (p.DRPCovDur/1440) - s.UDC_SafetyStock) as NetNeed 
       from SKU s, SKUPlanningParam p 
       where s.Item = p.Item and s.Loc = p.Loc group by s.Item, s.Loc, p.MinDRPQty
     ) a where a.Item = s.Item and a.Loc = s.Loc and ROWNUM = 1
);
```

It's not clear what you what to update, I suppose it's the SKU table

" and ROWNUM = 1" this condition is unclear and added in order to prevent multiple results in the correlated subquery.

Some info

```
select 
    s.Item as Item, 
    s.Loc as Loc, 
    p.MinDRPQty as MinDRPQty,  
    SUM (...)
...
group by s.Item, s.Loc, p.MinDRPQty
```

It means that result can be something like this

Row 1: item=1, loc=1, MinDRPQty=1, netNeed=100500
Row 2: item=1, loc=1, MinDRPQty=2, netNeed=500

Suppose there is one row with item=1, loc=1 in the table SKU.

When you make the update described above there is a problem: for row "item=1, loc=1" Oracle does't know which netNeed to choose (100500 or 500). That's why I put "and ROWNUM = 1" (any first row that was found). But I'm not sure if it makes sense in your case. Maybe you need some extra condition here!

Comment: It was SKU. Thanks for the ROWNUM and nullif additions as well. This works wonderfully.

Comment: @user2529787 I've updated the answer. Are you sure that it works as you wanted? There was no enough information in your question, that's why I put AND ROWNUM = 1 (to show the whole idea)

Comment: I don't have any multiple rows involved as you are mentioning, at least not with this data. But it is a very good tool for me to have for future use. Thanks for the explanation. Very helpful.

Comment: Multisync - It does work as I was hoping. Thank you.